# How to access variable from a Drupal behaviour in another function?

Tags: javascript

Im working on JavaScript which is within this function.

```
(function($) {
      function initForms() {

        $('.header').once('header-form', function () {
            // my code here
        });

      }
}
```

In a separate Drupal behaviour I have a variable that I need to access:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {

      var someVar = something; 

    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

How can I access the variable someVar in my first block of code?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a plain JavaScript question, since Drupal doesn't change JavaScript syntax. `someVar` is a local variable for an object method. Making it a public variable of that object is the first step. If you are writing that code, why don't you put all in the same `(function($) {})` block? Also, the first block is not getting any parameter to replace `$`.